# Can I develop for Elementary OS AppCenter in Java?

Tags: java, vala, elementary-os

The official language for developing for elementary-OS AppCenter is Vala. I was wondering if i can develop for eOS AppCenter in java language? I Know java to some extent a would master it if Elementary allow me to develop for it. On the other hand Vala would be a total new language for me.

Comment: Vala and Java aren't that much far apart, maybe have a look here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ValaForJavaProgrammers

Answer (score 1):

The ElementaryOS AppCenter is basically just a GUI for the package repositories. And you can create a package using any language. That does not mean however, that it is generally a good idea to create an Elementary application in Java, it really depends on what your application does: for example, creating a GUI application in Java is a bad idea if good desktop integration is a goal.